# Spark - How to get the latest hour in S3 path?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

I'm using a Databricks notebook with Spark and Scala to read data from `S3` into a DataFrame:

`myDf = spark.read.parquet(s"s3a://data/metrics/*/*/*/)`. where `*` wildcards represent year/month/day.

Or I just hardcode it: `myDf = spark.read.parquet(s"s3a://data/metrics/2018/05/20/)`

Now I want to add an hour parameter right after the day. The idea is to obtain data from `S3` for the most recently available hour.

If I do `myDf = spark.read.parquet(s"s3a://data/metrics/2018/05/20/*)` then I'll get data for all hours of may 20th.

How is it possible to achieve this in a Databricks notebook without hardcoding the hour?

Answer (score 1):

Use timedate function

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

latest_hour = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 1)
```

You can also split them by year, month, day, hour

```
latest_hour.year
latest_hour.month
latest_hour.day
latest_hour.hour
```

Comment: am I correct that I should then pass the computed `latest_hour` instead of a wildcard like `s"s3a://data/metrics/2018/05/20/latest_hour` ?

Comment: as I understand, `timedelta` is from Python datetime lib. But I'm using Scala. Do you know any similar approach with Scala?

Comment: Oh yeah, here's the code for Scala implementation `val now = Calendar.getInstance()` `val currentHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

Comment: This gets the recent hour of the current day. However in the path to S3 there may be a different date like `2018/05/20/` as shown above. How to get the latest hour (23) of the day from the path?

Comment: I get what you mean. I think I misunderstood your question. What you should do is get the latest hour in your s3 path. Parse this path to get the hour. Then add+1 to that hour.

Comment: could you please give an example on how to get the latest hour in s3 path?